# Changing list of different time units to same

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

My function currently outputs differencies between dates and gives a list as an output. However in the output some of the times are in hours and some in days but this causes problems to further computations. How can I change all the elements in the list to be given in hours? Example output:

```
`{Quantity[1051.25, "Hours"], Quantity[512.77, "Hours"], 
 Quantity[184.336, "Hours"], Quantity[501.193, "Hours"], 
 Quantity[675.129, "Hours"], Quantity[585.132, "Hours"], 
 Quantity[1315.69, "Hours"], Quantity[871.697, "Hours"], 
 Quantity[1364.36, "Hours"], Quantity[225.999, "Hours"], 
 Quantity[85.2831, "Days"], Quantity[1328.73, "Hours"], 
 Quantity[679.439, "Hours"], Quantity[990.738, "Hours"]}`
```

And most of the time there are even more days units than one. I was able to change them by hand using

```
`UnitConvert[Quantity[35.6575, "Days"], "Hours"]`
```

for example but I wasn't able to iterate this trough the list. Also it's not important in which units (or if you are able to output it in integers) the output has if all are the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what have your tried: `UnitConvert[list, "Hours"]`, not to mention `UnitConvert[#, "Hours"]&/@list`.

Answer (score 2):

Dates can be represented in many different ways. Two of them that spring to mind, are [`DateList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateList.html) and [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) (a third one is [`DateString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateString.html) but it sometimes can be tricky eg with ambiguous dates, so it won't be discussed here). The former is older than the later, but they both work with [`DateDifference`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateDifference.html) (or [`DatePlus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DatePlus.html), for that matter).

Let `diffs` contain the *differences* output (see question):

```
diffs = {Quantity[1051.25, "Hours"], Quantity[512.77, "Hours"], Quantity[184.336, "Hours"], 
  Quantity[501.193, "Hours"], Quantity[675.129, "Hours"], Quantity[585.132, "Hours"], 
  Quantity[1315.69, "Hours"], Quantity[871.697, "Hours"], Quantity[1364.36, "Hours"], 
  Quantity[225.999, "Hours"], Quantity[85.2831, "Days"], Quantity[1328.73, "Hours"], 
  Quantity[679.439, "Hours"], Quantity[990.738, "Hours"]};
```

Then,

```
input=FoldList[DatePlus[#1, #2] &, DateList[], diffs];
```

produces a list of dates that have successive differences *equal to* the ones in `diff`. Alternatively, one could have used `DateObject`, instead of `DateList`.

The following line produces the same output as the one stored in `diff`, but presented in the same unit, namely `"Hours"`.

```
DateDifference[#1, #2, "Hour"] & @@@ Partition[input, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}]
```

> ```
> {Quantity[1051.25, "Hours"], Quantity[512.77, "Hours"], Quantity[184.336, "Hours"], 
>   Quantity[501.193, "Hours"], Quantity[675.129, "Hours"], Quantity[585.132, "Hours"], 
>   Quantity[1315.69, "Hours"], Quantity[871.697, "Hours"], Quantity[1364.36, "Hours"], 
>   Quantity[225.999, "Hours"], Quantity[2046.79, "Hours"], Quantity[1328.73, "Hours"], 
>   Quantity[679.439, "Hours"], Quantity[990.738, "Hours"]}
> ```

The point of his exercise is to show that depending on how your input data looks like, you can produce the required output (in the desired units) *without* having the need to transform the output, after the fact.

Assuming that the hypothetical data-that are spaced as shown in `diffs`-are a list of lists (as in `data`-see below) then `f@@@Partition[data, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}]` can operate on *successive pairs* of input eg

```
 BlockRandom[
   (* create a list of date-value pairs *)
   data = FoldList[{DatePlus[#1[[1]], #2], RandomReal[]} &, {DateObject[], RandomReal[]}, diffs];

   (* produce the a list of hour difference-value difference pair for the entries of data *)
   {DateDifference[#1[[1]], #2[[1]], "Hour"], -#1[[-1]] + #2[[-1]]} & @@@Partition[data, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}], RandomSeeding -> 12345667]
```

> ```
> {{Quantity[1051.25, "Hours"], -0.280484}, {Quantity[512.77, "Hours"], 0.680484}, 
>     {Quantity[184.336, "Hours"], -0.111469}, {Quantity[501.193, "Hours"], -0.587604}, 
>     {Quantity[675.129, "Hours"], 0.932254}, {Quantity[585.132, "Hours"], -0.38131}, 
>     {Quantity[1315.69, "Hours"], 0.0046715}, {Quantity[871.697, "Hours"], -0.00360121}, 
>     {Quantity[1364.36, "Hours"], -0.379791}, {Quantity[225.999, "Hours"], -0.164225}, 
>     {Quantity[2046.79, "Hours"], 0.344222}, {Quantity[1328.73, "Hours"], 0.432163}, 
>     {Quantity[679.439, "Hours"], 0.0307164}, {Quantity[990.738, "Hours"], 0.170255}}
> ```

In this case, `f` was set up as `{DateDifference[#1[[1]], #2[[1]], "Hour"], -#1[[-1]] + #2[[-1]]} &` in order to take into account the structure of the input (list of pairs *date*-*value*).